# What is the use of % symbol in unix

Tags: unix, echo

Example.sh :

```
SERVICE="${0##*/}";
SERVICE="${SERVICE%.sh}"
echo $SERVICE
```

---

The above script provides Shellscript name as the output.But, how exactly it works ?
What is the purpose of line 1 and 2 ?
Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SERVICE="${0##*/}";**

`${x}` where *x* is a number returns the command line parameter value identified by index *x*. If *x* is 0, it returns the scriptname itself, including the path.
The operation `##*/` strips the path from that value.

After this operation, `SERVICE` contains the scriptname + extension but without the path.

**SERVICE="${SERVICE%.sh}"**

> When the percent sign (%) is used in the pattern `${variable%substring}`, it will return the content of the variable with the shortest occurrence of substring deleted from the back of the variable.

So after this operation `.sh` will be stripped from the value in the `${SERVICE}` variable. Now `SERVICE` contains the scriptname without path and without extension.

Comment: Thanks Wouter. What is the purpose of first line SERVICE="${0##*/}"; and is there any purpose/advantage of using ${variable%substring} instead of using ${variable} ?

Comment: Refined my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation.                                           Variable=Username
    Variable=${Variable:?"is required."}
    echo $Variable  . This is also works same as above ?